# web2py: correctly assign user to group upon registration

Tags: web2py

In my app I'd like to have a user be assigned to one of two auth groups, 'authgroup1' and 'authgroup2', depending on how they get registered.  Let's say I have two controllers, called 'group1' and 'group2', and they look something like this:

```
group1.py:
    @auth.requires_login()
    def index(): ...

group2.py:
    @auth.requires_login()
    def index(): ...
```

Essentially what I want to have happen is that if a user goes to group1/index.html and registers from there, he gets assigned to 'authgroup1', and if he goes to group2/index.html and has to register, he gets assigned to 'authgroup2'.

I was hoping to do this by adding a callback for registration:

```
db.py:
    ...
    def assignGroup(form):
        if we got here from group1:
            auth.add_membership(authgroup1_id, auth.user_id)
        else:
            auth.add_membership(authgroup2_id, auth.user_id)

    auth.settings.register_onaccept.append(assignGroup)
```

The question is, within assignGroup(), how do I test which controller (group1 or group2) got us here?  Can the controller set a variable somewhere such that db.py can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried request.controller == 'group1' or request.controller == 'group2' ?
http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching